# HTML tables next to each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to place many tables next to each other. At the moment I am using `float:left` and a fixed width, but the tables get placed like this:

[image: Wrong positions]

But I want them to be placed like this:

[image: Right positions]

Is this even possible without JavaScript? And if it is, how do I have to do it?

EDIT:

I am not using tables, because I do not know how many columns I have. On large screens I want to have more than on small ones.
Some demo-code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/9M4jn/

Comment: on every new row element, use `clear:left`. also please provide a demo page.

Comment: You should add your code here, an image can hide many different layouts.

Comment: Do you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/rP4uY/

Comment: @vsync I have edited my first post with some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap a div around your tables, give it a width, and then give your tables the CSS property `display: inline-block;`

**CSS**

```
div.tables table {
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
div.tables {
    width:500px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tables">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col 1</th>
                <th>col 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- snip............. -->

</div>
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j85Y9/2/

Comment: thank you for your help, but as you can see in my edit, I want the numbers of columns to be dynamic..

Comment: @Pinguin895 try this one.. updated to be a little more dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

table {
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 30%;
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

</style>

<!-- horrible placeholder data, hopefully the real tables have semantic markup -->
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2<br>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3<br>3<br>3</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>4<br>4</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>5</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>6<br>5<br>5</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>7</td></tr></table>
```

(Note, example does not contain compatibility hacks for older browsers. See the link for guidance on that)

Comment: This would be the chosen answer if we were in 2016 or his system was designed for internal use, but in real life I doubt he could afford the compatibility compromise.

Comment: Browser support for Flexbox is pretty good these days. I'm working on a site where we use progressive enhancement to server a degraded layout to IE8. Everything else has insufficient market share among the current users of the site to worry about.

Comment: Ah, and I see the question has been updated with "I am not using tables, because I do not know how many columns I have.", so I think this is the only solution that will work with that constraint.

Comment: thank you! This works well on updated browsers. If no other answer with a solution for old browsers comes up within the next few hours, I am going to accept this.

Comment: how can you say support is good when it barely reaches IE10. support must be maintained in these days all the way to IE8. unless, it is an in-house app/page.

Comment: @vsync — Because the market share for IE9 and IE10 is relatively tiny. Any system which runs them is very likely to get updated to IE11 through Windows Update. IE8 blips up in market share because it is the newest version of IE that will run on Windows XP (which is now no longer supported at all by Microsoft). Last time I looked at stats (for a particular site, YMMV, your decision should be based on *your* site's stats) IE8 was 0.5% and IE9 and 10 were less than that. For a lot of people, serving a degraded layout to users of old-IE is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Place your tables inside a Table like this :

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>#TABLES1#</td>
  <td>#TABLES2#</td>
  <td>#TABLES3#</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>#TABLES3#</td>
  <td>#TABLES4#</td>
  <td>#TABLES6#</td>
 </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

Comment: Nest tables are a very non-semantic technique from the 1990s that should be avoided.

Comment: see my edit for a reason why I don't want to use tables

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you want every 4th table in new row. For this, add a "clear" after every 3rd table.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: If you are going to use `clear`, then put it on the tables, don't add extra elements.

Comment: thank you for your help, but as you can see in my edit, I want the numbers of columns to be dynamic..